# EXT3-fs error (device dm-10)

Tags: rhel5, ext3

I got this log error below:

```
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159746
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159747
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159748
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159749
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159750
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_free_blocks_sb: bit already cleared for block 8159751
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_free_blocks_sb: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_reserve_inode_write: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_truncate: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_reserve_inode_write: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_orphan_del: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_reserve_inode_write: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10) in ext3_delete_inode: Journal has aborted
Aug  1 20:44:01 TDBP24LV kernel: EXT3-fs error (device dm-10): ext3_journal_start_sb: Detected aborted journal
```

Could someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your filesystem switched automatically to readonly mode until now.

It is a general failure in your fs. It was probably caused by a write failure.

If your fs is yet writable, mount it to readonly (`mount /the/fs/mount/path -o remount,ro`). If you can't do that, first you had to kill any process who wants/could write anything there (you can find them with an `lsof -n|grep /the/fs/mount/path`).

Then run a hard filesystem check (`e2fsck -f -p -C0 /dev/device/path`). If you don't like to press `y` a thousand times, use a `-y` flag instead of `-p` as well - although in this case you will say automatically "yes" to every, potentially destructive actions of the filesystem repair tool.

After that, you could remount it writable again (`mount /the/fs/mount/path -o remount,rw`).

If you can reboot without problems (i.e. you aren't working on your parters mission critical server 5000 km awhile), it weren't surely a bad practice to make this from a the root shell of a readonly rescue system.

You can calculate with same data loss as well, although don't have any real fear from such cryptic error messages, even if there are so many. Your filesystem has probably only a few damage, yet.

Comment: I would not use the `-y` option for fsck except as a last resort. Rather I would first try with `-p` instead like `e2fsck -f -p -C0 /dev/device/path`, and if that doesn't work, then try to leave it out like `e2fsck -f -C0 /dev/device/path`. Running it from the rescue system is good advice.

Comment: @kasperd Thank you - I changed my post to not suggesting potentially destructive actions by default.

Comment: Thanks. It's already solved but I'd like to know if error become repetitive, is there any patch or a bugfix to correct it? I'm in RHEL5.9

Comment: @user3863795 Some older redhat have known bugs in its ext3 driver, maybe you hit this problem. Check that with google. If not, my next try were some type of hardware problem. Does this happen only on this filesystem, or everywhere?

Comment: Only on this filesystem and just on one partition (dm-10)

Comment: @user3863795 Then it is very mystic. Something should probably this filesystem periodically overwrite on the block level, OR there is an ext3 bug which happens only on this fs. No idea, you had to play a little bit with the fs.